# How to exclude seconds from DateTime.ToString()

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using DateTime.Now.ToString() in a windows service and it is giving me output like "7/23/2010 12:35:07 PM "
I want to exclude the second part, displaying only up to minute.

So how to exclude seconds from that format...?

Comment: please refer this http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: @Amit, could you mark an answer for this, please?

Answer (score 54):

Output it as short date pattern:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("g")
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for full documentation.

Comment: This is the best solution, since it gives what the OP wants in en-US culture but is also culture-dependent in general.

Comment: How does this solution satisfy this: "I want to exclude the second part, displaying only up to minute." ?

Comment: @JanMacháček "g" will not print seconds, but printing date and time like the question asks as long as the culture is set correctly on the thread.

Comment: Ah, you are right :) Sorry. "G" is with seconds, "g" is without.

Comment: Best answer, thanks :) "g"  General date/time pattern (short time).

Answer (score 22):

You need to pass in a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) to the `ToString()` function:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("g")
```

This option is culture aware.

For this kind of output you could also use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), if you want full control:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

This will output exactly the same regardless of culture.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 2):

please test:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like `DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm");`

for more information look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay language independent, you could use the following code (maybe in an [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613620(v=vs.110).aspx) (see second code snippet)) to remove only the seconds part from the string:

```cs
int index = dateTimeString.LastIndexOf(':');
if (index > -1) {
    dateTimeString = dateTimeString.Remove(index, 3);
}
```

Here's an implementation of the converter.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(string))]
public class DateTimeToStringConverter : Markup.MarkupExtension, IValueConverter {
    public DateTimeToStringConverter() : base() {
        DisplayStyle = Kind.DateAndTime;
        DisplaySeconds = true;
    }

    #region IValueConverter
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value == null) return string.Empty;
        if (!value is DateTime) throw new ArgumentException("The value's type has to be DateTime.", "value");

        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)value;

        string returnValue = string.Empty;

        switch (DisplayStyle) {
            case Kind.Date:
                returnValue = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
                break;
            case Kind.Time:
                returnValue = dateTime.ToLongTimeString();
                break;
            case Kind.DateAndTime:
                returnValue = dateTime.ToString();
                break;
        }

        if (!DisplaySeconds) {
            int index = returnValue.LastIndexOf(':');

            if (index > -1) {
                returnValue = returnValue.Remove(index, 3);
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    #endregion

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return this;
    }

    #region Properties
    public Kind DisplayStyle { get; set; }

    public bool DisplaySeconds { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public enum Kind {
        Date,
        Time,
        DateAndTime
    }
}
```

You can also use it in XAML as a markup extension:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationTimestamp, Converter={local:DateTimeToStringConverter DisplayStyle=DateAndTime, DisplaySeconds=False}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString()`

Comment: This will only display the date part. You would have to add ToShortTimeString as well.