# Remove seconds from local time but keep format

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Assume you have UTC time string converted to local time:

```
utcTimeString.ToLocalTime().ToString(); => "01/31/2012 12:00:00 PM"
```

How to remove seconds from result string but keep format (set in phone settings?)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude seconds from DateTime.ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316083/how-to-exclude-seconds-from-datetime-tostring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
utcTimeString.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

As an alternative, you can use

```
String.Format("{0:d} {0:t}",utcTimeString.ToLocalTime());
String.Format("{0:g}",utcTimeString.ToLocalTime());
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: As far as I know, this will always output date separated by / which is what I don't want -> I want to keep separator set in system (phone) settings.

Comment: The alternatives I posted will output using culture-specific information for date and time, so it'll even switch month/day depending on culture, and are basically equivalent.

Comment: Hardcoding the format string loses the local format and seems to be the exact opposite of what the question is asking. Answer from Steve Danner below is better.

Answer (score 7):

To keep the current culture info, you could do:

```
utcTimeString.ToLocalTime().ToShortDateString() + 
" " + 
utcTimeString.ToLocalTime().ToShortTimeString();
```

Answer (score 6):

I would go for

```
var date = utcTimeString.ToLocalTime();
date = date.AddSeconds(-date.Second);
string yourStr = date.ToString();
```

Comment: "date.AddSeconds(-date.Second);" is the most clever piece of code I have seen today...very simple and is the best solution if you want to keep the Date and Time in the DateTime variable type...which I did.