# Remove seconds part from time C#

Tags: c#, datetime

My code snippet is like this

```
DateTime.Parse("2014-04-24T10:00:00").TimeOfDay
```

and this produces an output

```
10:00:00
```

But I want to get the result as

```
10:00
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: The output isn't really a string - it's just a `TimeSpan`. A `TimeSpan` doesn't have a notion of "having seconds or not" or a particular format. What are you doing with the `TimeSpan` after this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude seconds from DateTime.ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316083/how-to-exclude-seconds-from-datetime-tostring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ToShortTimeString()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this format string on the `DateTime`: `HH:mm`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2014-04-24T10:00:00");
string output = dt.ToString("HH:mm");  // hh if you want 12h clock
```

Another way is using [`DateTime.ToShortTimeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string output = dt.ToShortTimeString()
```

With .NET 4+ you can also use [`TimeSpan.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since it now implements `IFormattable`, although i find it difficult to remember how to escape it properly:

```
string output = dt.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can format it with `hh\:mm` format.

```
DateTime.Parse("2014-04-24T10:00:00").TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

Take a look at;

- [`Custom TimeSpan Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[`TimeSpan.ToString(String)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires .NET Framework 4.0 or higher by the way.